# javascript problems while generating form

Tags: javascript

everything working as my desire but when I click on book **room button** it can not generate input field for me but its shows as [`object HTMLFormElement`] here is my code

```
function booking(roomBooking){  
    var f = document.createElement("form");
    var in1 = document.createElement("input");
    in1.type = "text";
    in1.name = "user_name";
    in1.id = "user_name1";
    f.appendChild(in1);
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=f;    
}
```

I want to show form when I clicked on book room button.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

You should just apply your f variable to "#name" element by using appendChild() function, because "f" it's an object and you cannot directly use it.

```
function booking(roomBooking) {
    var f = document.createElement("form");
    var in1 = document.createElement("input");

    in1.type = "text";
    in1.name = "user_name";
    in1.id = "user_name1";
    f.appendChild(in1);

    document.getElementById("name").appendChild(f);    
}
```